# How to search an argument/flag/option in man with a line break?

Tags: man, line

In `man` argument/flag/option chapters generally include a line break, as with:

```
-s
    silent
```

How could I find only the `-s` which includes a line break after it, just as in the above example?

The purpose is to prevent a case where I find an `-s` inside a text block (i.e. without a line break after it).

Comment: I don't quite understand: If the option is `-s`, and it has no parameter, you would search for "-s" only. If `-s` has a parameter it would be on the same line usually. Maybe explain what you try to do actually.

Comment: @U.Windl I have explained what I tried to do, to search for `-s` before a line break but in `man` for `curl` I found it in another way, **in the end of** a block of text and without any such line break. Why? I don't know, the relevant author of `man` for `curl` knows.

Comment: I checked for curl-7.66.0 ("16 Dec 2016"): There I see "-s, --silent" on a single line. That manual page was created with "curl project gen.pl man page generator".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what pager you use.

If using the `less` pager, search strings (as when you type `/` or `?`) are actually extended regular expressions (with `less`-specific extensions).

As a regular expression, `-s$` would match on a `-s` (or `-S` as searches ignore case by default in `less` when called by `man` unless the search pattern contains an uppercase letter, type `-i` for case sensitive) that is at the end of the line. `-s[[:space:]]*$` would match on `-s`, followed by 0 or more spacing characters followed by the end of the line.

With the `most` pager, searches are just plain string that are found in the contents of lines, so you're left without an option there.

You can specify which pager `man` will use to display the formatted man page with the `$PAGER` environment variable. With the implementation from `man-db`, you can also specify it with the `-P` option which takes precedence over the `$MANPAGER` environment variable which itself takes precedence over the `$PAGER` variable.

Which pager is used by default depends on the system and `man` implementation. On my system (Debian), `man` (from `man-db`) invokes the `pager` command (which is managed as a *dpkg alternative* and by default is `less`), but has some `less`-specific configurations (it sets a number of `LESS*` environment variables).

You could also do `man some-topic | less` to pipe the formatted output to `less` by yourself, or: `man some-topic | less '+/-s$'` for `less` to start searching for that pattern upon start, but beware that with the man-db implementation of `man`, redirecting the output disables the formatting.

Instead you can give `less` its list of options with the `$LESS` environment variable, but note that `$` has a special meaning there, and would need to be escaped:

```
LESS='--use-backslash +/-s\$' man -P less some-topic
```

Comment: I don't know which pager `man` uses in my WSL-Ubuntu 18.04 system (?) If I make a search in `man` with `-s$` I get: "Pattern not found".

Comment: I think it's because the man doesn't have that, rather it has entries starting as `-x,` I don't recall commas added in a few other manuals I've read.

Comment: @Lahor, that sounds like an error `less` would return. Does pressing `V` mention `less <some-version>` at the bottom. Here it's possible there are whitespace characters after the `-s`. So searching for `-s[[:space:]]*$` (`-s\s*$` might also work) may given you more results.

Comment: Yes, pressing V gave `less 487`. I got Pattern not found, after searching -s[[:space:]]*$`. echo $PAGER output was an empty line.

Comment: @Lahor, that would suggest there is no line matching that pattern in your man page. Are you sure there is?

Comment: Now after manually going through all similar entries in this manual I think (not sure) that there isn't... But I think that `-s$` is what I will use in next cases (instead s, any other letter, if needed).

Comment: In second thought, `-s,| ` would be better right, I mean comma or whitespace which are more plausible than a line break. Right?

Comment: @Lahor, most like `-s(,| |$)`. See also `-s\>` for `-s` followed by a word-boundary (assuming your system's regexps support that `\>` extension).